# How to do Programatic dynamic product configurator - image generator

Tags: node.js, image-processing

Am having a requirement which is to build site very similar to shoesofprey.com  designer. They have atleast from 4 - 12 different attributes to prepare the output image, by shoe type selection and the other available attributes based on previous attribute option selected and here its happening with dynamic image combining for the attribute options that user pick - so  far I haven't got clear picture on how to or what platform/technology that I can use to get there. I did more research for this one alone particularly and read more about their site problems or how good they are and not even single post mentions any tech aspect behind the design.

Normal image replacement based product configurator in which normally javascript does the basic magic of replacing and showing user that - that's what they are going to get and in that client has to prepare every combination and it was worked with variety of Sites so far.

Here client is certain that they cant and wont able to do that much combinations and based on their requirement/business model I too certain that - the manual generation of every combination will take life time for many designers and its not going to happen.

If suggestion for solution to this is in Node.js or ROR or Java based app - its better since I used these in intermediate level or at-least low level to follow up.

> One important thing client does not want to go with any third party
>   services to generate this image chains and they want their own image
>   modeling solution.

Any suggestion on this will be really helpful and much appreciated since so many developers have had very similar problems at-least for basic projects and so far I haven't got not even single possible way for this.